# In haskell finalize foreign pointers immediately after they are no longer referenced

Tags: haskell

Is there a way to make sure that objects of some specific type (basically `ForeignPtr`) are garbage-collected very aggressively? I have some kind of simple type like this:

```
data SomePtr = SomePtr { ptr :: ForeignPtr CUChar, size :: CSize }
alloc :: CSize -> IO SomePtr
free :: SomePtr -> IO ()
free = finalizeForeignPtr . ptr
```

I think that the standard theory is that reference counting (which is how I would do this myself in, say, C++) is slower than the GC that ghc uses, which is why it doesn't use it. But the problem for me is that when working with externally allocated objects, like GPU memory, the promise that it will *eventually* be freed isn't enough. The memory is quite scarce and as far as I can tell, the `ForeignPtr` finalizer is not actually called when I would like it to be. I would like the memory to be freed as soon as possible, so I end up calling `finalizeForeignPtr` myself.

Is there some way to tell ghc to be really aggressive in destroying some specific types of objects?

Or I am going about this the wrong way?

Here is example code to illustrate what I mean:

#### Haskell

```haskell
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}
import Foreign.ForeignPtr.Safe
import Foreign.Ptr
import Foreign.Marshal.Alloc
import Foreign.Storable
import Control.Monad
import Foreign.C.Types
import Text.Printf

data FPtr = FPtr { fptr :: ForeignPtr CUChar, size :: CSize }

foreign import ccall "falloc" falloc :: CSize -> Ptr (Ptr CUChar) -> IO CInt
foreign import ccall "&ffree" ffree :: FunPtr (Ptr CUChar -> IO ())

newFPtr :: CSize -> IO FPtr
newFPtr size =
  do alloca $ \ptr -> do
       result <- falloc size ptr
       printf "Result: %d\n" (fromIntegral result :: Int)
       fptr <- newForeignPtr ffree =<< peek ptr
       return FPtr{..}

freeFPtr :: FPtr -> IO ()
freeFPtr = finalizeForeignPtr . fptr

main :: IO ()
main = forM_ [1 .. 5] $ const work
  where
  work = do x <- newFPtr 1024
            -- freeFPtr x
            return ()
```

#### C++

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

extern "C" {
int falloc(size_t size, unsigned char** ptr);
void ffree(unsigned char* ptr);
}

int some_counter = 0;

int falloc(size_t size, unsigned char** ptr) {
  some_counter++;
  printf("falloc(%lu, %#lx, %#lx); %d\n",
    size, (unsigned long)ptr, (unsigned long)*ptr, some_counter);
  *ptr = new unsigned char[size];
  return 0;
}

void ffree(unsigned char* ptr) {
  printf("ffree(%#lx)\n", (unsigned long)ptr);
  delete[] ptr;
}
```

#### Output

```
falloc(1024, 0x100606010, 0); 1
Result: 0
falloc(1024, 0x100606028, 0); 2
Result: 0
falloc(1024, 0x100606040, 0); 3
Result: 0
falloc(1024, 0x100606058, 0); 4
Result: 0
falloc(1024, 0x100606070, 0); 5
Result: 0
ffree(0x101026400)
ffree(0x101027800)
ffree(0x101027c00)
ffree(0x101028000)
ffree(0x101028400)
```

#### Desired output

```
falloc(1024, 0x100606010, 0); 1
Result: 0
ffree(0x101026400)
falloc(1024, 0x100606028, 0); 2
Result: 0
ffree(0x100802200)
falloc(1024, 0x100606040, 0); 3
Result: 0
ffree(0x100802200)
falloc(1024, 0x100606058, 0); 4
Result: 0
ffree(0x100802200)
falloc(1024, 0x100606070, 0); 5
Result: 0
ffree(0x100802200)
```

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736780/how-long-should-i-expect-a-garbage-collection-to-take-before-removing-an-opaque

Comment: @leftaroundabout Thank you for the link, your question did not show up for me when I searched. This is a duplicate I guess, but that question is two years old, and I would like to see if I get a better answer than `performGC`. Calling `performGC` seems a worse solution than calling `finalizeForeignPtr`.

Comment: Since there doesn't seem to be a direct way to influence GHC, what if you would use something like `withForeignMemory :: CSize -> (FPtr -> IO a) -> IO a`, which allocates the foreign memory, uses the given function, and then deallocates it? It's still more verbose than it needs to be, though.

Comment: @Zeta Like `alloca`? I suppose so, but I do often need long-lived foreign pointers that should escape the scope of that `FPtr -> IO a` function.

Comment: GC is faster than reference counting (often anyway, not always) because it isn't deterministic (effectively anyway). If you want deterministic deallocation you'll have to live with there being some overhead - mental or performance depending on how you do it, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we want to be independent of the GHC's garbage collection, we need to introduce some kind of determinism and therefore explicit deallocation. Allocation is usually something of type `IO a`, and the corresponding deallocation of type `a -> IO ()` (just as your example).

Now, what if we had the following functions?

```
allocate  :: IO a -> (a -> IO ()) -> Alloc a
runAlloc  :: Alloc a -> IO a
```

`autoAllocate` should take both an allocation and deallocation and give you the result of the allocation in the new (superficial) `Alloc` monad, and `runAlloc` runs all actions and deallocations. Your example wouldn't change that much, except for the end:

```
allocateFPtr size = autoAllocate (newFPtr size) freeFPtr

main :: IO ()
main = forM_ [1 .. 5] $ runAlloc . const work
  where
  work = do x <- allocateFPtr 1024
            return ()
```

Now, `allocate`, `runAlloc` and `Alloc` already exists in [`resourcet`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/resourcet-1.1.2.3) as [`allocate`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/resourcet-1.1.2.3/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Resource.html#v:allocate), [`runResourceT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/resourcet-1.1.2.3/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Resource.html#v:runResourceT) and [`ResourceT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/resourcet-1.1.2.3/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Resource.html#t:ResourceT), and the actual code would look like this:

```
allocateFPtr size = fmap snd $ allocate (newFPtr size) freeFPtr

main :: IO ()
main = forM_ [1 .. 5] $ runResourceT . const work
  where
  work = do x <- allocateFPtr 1024
            return ()
```

Result:

```
falloc(1024, 0x1e04014, 0); 1
Result: 0
ffree(0x6abc60)
falloc(1024, 0x1e04020, 0); 2
Result: 0
ffree(0x6abc60)
falloc(1024, 0x1e0402c, 0); 3
Result: 0
ffree(0x6abc60)
falloc(1024, 0x1e04038, 0); 4
Result: 0
ffree(0x6abc60)
falloc(1024, 0x1e04044, 0); 5
Result: 0
ffree(0x6abc60)
```

But you said that some of your pointers should actually live longer. That's also not a problem, since `allocate` actually returns `m (ReleaseKey, a)`, and `ReleaseKey` can be used to either release the memory earlier than `runResourceT` (using [`release`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/resourcet-1.1.2.3/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Resource.html#v:release)) or remove the automatic release mechanism (using [`unprotect`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/resourcet-1.1.2.3/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Resource.html#v:unprotect), which returns the deallocation action).

So, all in all, I guess your scenario could be handled well with `ResourceT`. After all, it's synopsis is "Deterministic allocation and freeing of scarce resources".

Comment: Thank you for the pointer to resourcet. It seems to be implemented with an internal set of deallocation actions to be run later. So the code you wrote down is executing the same actions, but in a slightly more abstract way. I think this looks cleaner than what I had because the deallocation action is specified together with the allocation (not separately, later), and the whole thing is a little bit more automatic.

Answer (score 2):

You are thinking about this in the wrong way *for Haskell.*

In C++, RAII is used to ensure that resources are released -- promptly. Since C++ lacks a `finally` construct, there is no other way to ensure that resources are released in the presence of exceptions. Also, since C++ lacks a garbage collector, reference counting and RAII are the order of the day.

In Haskell (and other garbage collected languages), however, the situation is different. One does not rely on finalizers running promptly. In fact, one should not rely on finalizers running at all, since they could be delayed for an arbitrary amount of time if the amount of available memory is high enough -- and might *never be executed at all* if the program terminates before the finalizer (or even the garbage collector) has a chance to run since the object became unreachable.

Instead, one uses explicit resource deallocation. This seems bad, but isn't. For reasons of memory safety, one should put the object in a "zombie" state, so that any further attempts to use the object throw exceptions (since they are bugs).

Alternatively, if the resources are such that they are automatically deallocated on process exit, one can rely on finalizers -- but note that they may not be called promptly (as you mentioned), and so an explicit `performGC` may be needed if the resource is exhausted. I suspect that not knowing when the life of truly scarce resources is over (at least conservatively) is probably a code smell even in C++ -- it means that there is no upper bound on the amount of the resource consumed.

Answer (score 2):

In the very limited case where you are concerned about just freeing some memory that you can have live on the haskell heap, there is a special edge case available to you.

`mallocForeignPtr` allocates the memory as a pinned mutable byte array on the haskell heap, so when the `ForeignPtr` (and the mutable byte array) get GC'd, the memory gets automatically reclaimed with no finalizer invocation.

This is considerably cheaper than adding a manual hook to call some `free` corresponding to a system `malloc`, but only in the limited circumstances where you can live with the limitations.

However, if you are relying on freeing another resource (e.g. through a file handle object, or memory or resource IDs out on the GPU or something else) you're still hosed.

In general, don't rely on the GC to free up valuable external resources for you, except as a sort of "apology" pass for leaked things during, say, exceptions or the like. Your usual control flow should still free up the external resources you use.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering! This is a rather old question, but I want to say that I agree with what you said and this is pretty much the approach I've been using.